# xdg-open 'Segmentation Fault': it took to long time then throw error

Tags: linux, mime, xdgutils

well I noticed `xdg-open` command not working as expected for opnening files or urls
and after a deep investigation I found the below

**Trace:**

```
bash -x xdg-open "https://suckless.org"
```

after running the above line I found the code enters an infinite loop of recursion which cause to terminate with seg fault
the function with the problem:
/usr/bin/xdg-open:819

```
for d in $dir/*/; do
    [ -d "$d" ] && search_desktop_file "$default" "$d" "$target"
done
```

But why this happens in the first place, well it was fairly simple which I'm going to discuss below

**Root Cause:**

1. xdg-open tries first to get all possible locations for target applications like

   - ~/.local/share/applications
   - /usr/local/share/applications
   - /usr/share/application
2. if there's any child dir there it loop throug it recursively
3. the problem happens when a directory name has a space

   - in my case it was like this

> ls -la ~/.local/share/applications//wine//Programs//Rockstar Games/
> ls: cannot access
> '~/.local/share/applications//wine//Programs//Rockstar': No such file
> or directory Games/: total 12 drwxrwxrwx  3 void void 4096 Feb 26
> 19:54 . drwx------ 43 void void 4096 May 29 12:32 .. drwxr-xr-x  5
> void void 4096 May 24 22:36 epic-games-store
> this got the tool to look up in a very different files which causes to loop infintly

Fix:

- the easy fix is to change the dir name and remove any space, better if you can keep only desktop files inside the ~/.local/share/applications

Answer (score 0):

**Fix:**
the easy fix is to change the dir name and remove any space, better if you can keep only desktop files inside the ~/.local/share/applications